# Issue with AVAudioPlayer gives error when click at Play button

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am programing an audio player using "AVFoundation.h". I've issues with Updating Progress bar, Hence when I click at play button my app gives error. I am attaching both code samples & error report. can anyone sort this out?

```
-(void)updateProgress {
NSInteger durationMinutes = [self.audioPlayer duration] / 60;
NSInteger durationSeconds = [self.audioPlayer duration]  - durationMinutes * 60;

NSInteger currentTimeMinutes = [self.audioPlayer currentTime] / 60;
NSInteger currentTimeSeconds = [self.audioPlayer currentTime]  - currentTimeMinutes * 60;
NSString *progressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d / %d:%02d", currentTimeMinutes, currentTimeSeconds, durationMinutes, durationSeconds];
self.timeLabel.text = progressString;

self.progressBar.progress = [self.audioPlayer currentTime] / [self.audioPlayer duration];

NSNumber *numCurrentTimeSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentTimeSeconds];
NSNumber *numDurationSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:durationSeconds];

NSString *songTitle = [self.selectedFilePath lastPathComponent];
NSString *artistName = @"MyPlayer";
MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];


MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[songTitle, artistName, albumArt, numDurationSeconds, numCurrentTimeSeconds] forKeys:@[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime]];
[infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:infoDict];        }
```

When pressed Build & Run app goes successfully started in simulator, I've taken 2 images of active Console 
1. before clicking at play button.

2. After clicking play button. when app goes crash.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwmMS.png)

now please suggest me what I should do at this point? so that my app start working smoothly...
Thanks
Faiz.

---

After following instructions by Losiowaty answer last day. those yellow issues are removed but still my programing gives same error when I click at play button. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmyoW.png)

This time I am uploading complete code and highlighting few things due to which I think error is occurring.
Please take a look at my mainwviewcontroller.m class code.

```
    @interface MainViewController ()
    @end
    @implementation MainViewController
    @synthesize audioPlayer;
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"audio session initialized successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error initializing audio session: %@", [error description]);
    }


    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init] ;

    [volumeView setFrame:self.airPlayView.bounds];
    [self.airPlayView addSubview:volumeView];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(caughtInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(routeChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFilePicker"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        FileViewController *fileViewController = (FileViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        fileViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

#pragma mark - file picker delegate methods

-(void)cancel
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)didFinishWithFile:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    self.selectedFilePath = filePath;

    NSString *relativeFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:relativeFilePath];

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"audio player initialized successfully");

        self.titleLabel.text = self.selectedFilePath;

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        NSString *songTitle = [filePath lastPathComponent];
        NSString *artistName = @"MyPlayer";
        MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[songTitle, artistName, albumArt] forKeys:@[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork]];
        [infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:infoDict];

        [self play:nil];


    } else {
        NSLog(@"error initializing audio player: %@", [error description]);
    }


    //dismiss the file picker
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [animation stopAnimating];

    } else {
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation3.png"],nil];

        [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:2000];
        animation.animationDuration = 0.5;
        [animation startAnimating];

    }
    self.playbackInterrupted = NO;
}

-(IBAction)skipForward:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSTimeInterval desiredTime = self.audioPlayer.currentTime + 15.0f;
        if (desiredTime < self.audioPlayer.duration) {
            self.audioPlayer.currentTime = desiredTime;
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)skipBackward:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSTimeInterval desiredTime = self.audioPlayer.currentTime - 15.0f;
        if (desiredTime < 0) {
            self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0f;
        } else {
            self.audioPlayer.currentTime = desiredTime;
        }

    }
}

#pragma mark - Timer delegate

-(void)updateProgress
{
    NSInteger durationMinutes = [self.audioPlayer duration] / 60;
    NSInteger durationSeconds = [self.audioPlayer duration]  - durationMinutes * 60;

    NSInteger currentTimeMinutes = [self.audioPlayer currentTime] / 60;
    NSInteger currentTimeSeconds = [self.audioPlayer currentTime]  - currentTimeMinutes * 60;
    NSString *progressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld / %ld:%02ld", currentTimeMinutes,currentTimeSeconds, durationMinutes, durationSeconds];
    self.timeLabel.text = progressString;

    self.progressBar.progress = [self.audioPlayer currentTime] / [self.audioPlayer duration];

    NSNumber *numCurrentTimeSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:currentTimeSeconds];
    NSNumber *numDurationSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:durationSeconds];

    NSString *songTitle = [self.selectedFilePath lastPathComponent];
    NSString *artistName = @"MyPlayer";
    MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];


    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[songTitle, artistName, albumArt, numDurationSeconds, numCurrentTimeSeconds] forKeys:@[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime]];
        [infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:infoDict];

}

#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayer delegate methods

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        [self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [animation stopAnimating];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Remote control

-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [self play:nil];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            [self skipForward:nil];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [self skipBackward:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - audio interruption

-(void)caughtInterruption:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    NSNumber *type =[userInfo objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    if ([type integerValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan) {
        if (self.audioPlayer.playing) {
            [self.audioPlayer pause];
            [animation stopAnimating];
            self.playbackInterrupted = YES;
        }
    } else {
        if (self.audioPlayer.playing == NO && self.playbackInterrupted == YES) {
            [self.audioPlayer play];
            [animation startAnimating];
            self.playbackInterrupted = NO;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - route changed

-(void)routeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;

    NSNumber *reason =[userInfo objectForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey];
    switch ([reason integerValue]) {
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNoSuitableRouteForCategory:
            [self.audioPlayer stop];
            [animation stopAnimating];
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable:
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable:
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonWakeFromSleep:
            [self.audioPlayer pause];
            [animation stopAnimating];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}


@end
```

above code is error free & pretty clean, everything is clearly mentioned, I am using 4 buttons,

1. for Play & Pause
2. for seeking forward
3. for seeking backward
4. for entering into document directory for audio file picking

when I am pressing this fourth button it prepares for entering into another view  for picking audio file.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFilePicker"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        FileViewController *fileViewController = (FileViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        fileViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

I needs two things to accomplish

the first things which I needs to accomplish is that,

1. I don't wants to enter into next view, because I am testing my app into simulator where there is no physical audio file I can place or locate in simulator, hence I needs to avoid this thing just for my owns testing purpose. 
   Hence I am willing to add an audio mp3 file into NSBundle and wants to play this file when I press play button file starts playing & then Pause when pressing again. code for paying & pause is pretty clean working well. but for initializing file path is I think I've to initialize file path in viewDidload method by replacing above view did load by following code.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Nameofflie" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *pathAsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];


   NSError *error = nil;
   audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathAsURL error:&error];
      if (error == nil) {
       NSLog(@"audio session initialized successfully");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"error initializing audio session: %@", [error description]);
   }


   [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
   MPVolumeView *volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init] ;

   [volumeView setFrame:self.airPlayView.bounds];
   [self.airPlayView addSubview:volumeView];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

   [self becomeFirstResponder];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(caughtInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(routeChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
   ```

   }

this code also Runs & compiles pretty well but when pressing play button same error occurring. so please suggest me where to place following lines to play MP3 Music file placed from NSBudle .

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rabne" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *pathAsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathAsURL error:&error];
```

2. this point is totally different from  just above point number 1 which I am willing to accomplish. when after testing successfully, playing that NSBundle audio MP3 file. 
   I wants to work with my earlier code again, as the end user is not using my simulator, hence for end users I wants to have same option which already I accomplished in above `Mainviewcontroller.m` class,i.e. user have to press  4th number button for accessing their device's document directory file path. that works pretty well in my code. but the thing here I wants to point to or needs to sort out is that, if someone directly pressing very 1st play button without pressing 4th button for going & selecting an audio file, an alert view should appear with a message that first select a file by pressing fourth button and then click play button.  That's it I am willing to have in my code.

Comment: Can you click on the yellow triangles and show the warnings there? Also, when your app crashes there is a stack trace with a better description of the exception in the window under the code on the right. Could you expand it and paste the exception and stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your reply(suggestion), 
I already tried that many times, it gives option for minor change in very first issue with following. 
 NSString *progressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:02d / %ld:02d", currentTimeMinutes,(long)currentTimeSeconds, (long)durationMinutes, durationSeconds];

still another issue at same line occurring which says "data arguments not used by format string". & having nothing to fix this issue, & program still gives same error.

Comment: This warning simply means that you passed 4 numbers to format string but used only two of them in it. This seems irrelevant to the crash, as warnings seldom do, and that's why I also asked fot the stack trace and excpetion description from the console window.

Comment: let me add few more images of error reporting when I push play button app stopped working & displaying those errors. when I step over the process, attaching all the images.

Comment: I am using all four numbers, if you read that line clearly.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I'm specifically interested in the output of the highlitghted window : http://i.imgur.com/ReOHehy.png. Also, on a side note - you should be able to edit your own question, no need to post more information as answers.

Comment: No needs for saying sorry. its ok. & thanks for paying your time to this discussion.
lets see if someone else be able to sort out my issue. . .

Comment: If you could just expand the window with red border in this http://i.imgur.com/ReOHehy.png screenshot and copy and paste its contents after the crash than someone might. Without it, there isn't much to go on.

Comment: Losiowaty, please check now. edited version of my question. where I clearly provided active console area. when app launches successfully & after pressing play button when app goes crash. both snaps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception in screenshot #2, it looks that you are trying to insert a `nil` object into an array. The only place where you insert some objects into array is this line :

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[songTitle, artistName, albumArt, numDurationSeconds, numCurrentTimeSeconds] forKeys:@[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime]];
```

The second array, the one with the keys, looks ok, as it consisits of only system provided consts. The first one on the other hand has two objects than could be nil : `songTitle` and `albumArt`.

The reasons for these to be `nil` are :

1. `songTitle` may be `nil` if `self.selectedFilePath` is `nil`
2. `albumArt` - I'm not entirely sure, but it could end up being `nil` if your image was not found.

Please make sure that these two are not `nil` and everything should be working fine.

---

As to your warnings, these two :

```
NSNumber *numCurrentTimeSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentTimeSeconds];
NSNumber *numDurationSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:durationSeconds];
```

can be fixed by changing to `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` and are caused by the fact that `NSInteger` is a `typedef` for `long` and not `int`.

The warning on

```
NSString *progressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d / %d:%02d", currentTimeMinutes, currentTimeSeconds, durationMinutes, durationSeconds];
```

is caused by virtually the same thing. `%d` expects an `int`, and `NSInteger` is a `long`. Changing `%d` to `%ld` will fix it.

It is still my firm belief that these didn't cause the crash, especially based on the thrown exception which is pretty straightforward in stating what has happend.

---

The provided code confirms my assumptions - the crash happens because `self.selectedFilePath` is `nil` in `updateProgress` method resulting in `songTitle` also being `nil`. Why this happens? The only place in provided code where you set `self.selectedFilePath` is in `didFinishWithFile:` method, which I assume is a delegate method of `FileViewController`. If you don't present it and selected something there, that method is not called.

Now, if you want to setup this for testing, the easiest way would be to add this in your `viewDidLoad` :

```
NSError *error;
NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rabne" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *pathAsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathAsURL error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    self.selectedFilePath = @"test file"; // <<-- IMPORTANT
    self.titleLabel.text = self.selectedFilePath;
 } else {
    NSLog(@"error initializing audio player: %@", [error description]);
 }
```

just above `[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];`. This should get everything going.

On a side note : I'd also remove this line `self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` from `didFinishWithFile:` method - you also setup a timer in `play:` method, and it seems safer to do it once.

---

As to point #2 - I can give you a hint, that you know if a file is selected when `self.selectedFilePath != nil` and to take a look at [`UIAlertViewController` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController). The rest of work is left for you, as it was not a part of the original problem and has nothing to do with solving the crash. Also, you wouldn't learn anything that way :)

Comment: First of all thanks for your time & attention, 
let me follow your instructions & to see what happening now. will be back shortly with the results.

Comment: Recently I've added a screenshot in above question, which indicating issues. in the code. I think at that point there'll be something went wrong.  not at songTitle or albumArt. so what you says?

Comment: Thanks Losiowaty, after following your instructions one thing is resolved(lines with yellow issues are resolved now), as there exact same problem with those issues, when I replaced [NSNumber numberWithInt:] to [NSNumber numberWithInteger:] and "%d to %ld", there are no more issues in the code. 
 But still my app giving same error which since start it was giving. Let me add complete code of the mainviewcontroller.m class and to highlight few more things in my question above. I'll inform here shortly when after updating my question section.

Comment: If you do, then please don't do this as a screenshot, but rather copy and paste the code.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited version of question.   and to do let me know if still needs more details. or anything else missing...?

Comment: Thanks for your time & suggestion, I've read read your answer completely, hopefully do let you know after following your instructions which I m starting right now...